# Stripe Address and Payments Element interaction

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I want to have an Address Element and Payments Element in Stripe, in React.

It seems best if they are directly linked together within the same  context, to provide autocomplete without a Google API key and to give the "use same billing as shipping" address checkbox.

*However* I need to calculate taxes and shipping based on the shipping address before they can pay. So I need the shipping address *before* the payment intent client secret can be generated with the order cost, which I need *before* I can render the Payments element.

Do I just need to detach them into two separate Elements contexts, or is there a way to delay the payment intent but still render the Payments element next to the Address element?

Thanks!

Comment: Stripe allows you to present the PaymentElement without first creating a PaymentIntent: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/build-a-two-step-confirmation

You can keep the two Elements on the same page so you won't need a Google API key. You'll want to listen for change events on the Address Element and then calculate tax: https://stripe.com/docs/elements/address-element/collect-addresses?platform=web#web-retrieve-address